# Strange PHP syntax

Tags: php, syntax, if-statement, alternate, control-structure

I've been working on `PHP` for some time but today when I saw this it came as new to me:

```
if(preg_match('/foo.*bar/','foo is a bar')):
        echo 'success ';
        echo 'foo comes before bar';

endif;
```

To my surprise it also runs without error. Can  anyone enlighten me?

Thanks to all :)

Comment: as the answers below have said, this is an alternative syntax. It's also awfully painful to read IMO, please avoid this in your own code.

Comment: this kind of syntax is used in templates when you often open and close <?php?> and you use html in between. It is horrible and unreadable even in those cases, and should be avoided altogether.

Comment: @Lo'oris, I disagree with you. Using it in your templates can improve readability if you ask me: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788891/strange-php-syntax/2789008#2789008 for an example.

Comment: I agree with those who recommend against it.  Even in templates, as Lo'oris mentioned, it does almost nothing for readability.  But the main problem I have with it is that I haven't found an IDE which highlights matching if/endif or foreach/endforeach or any other alternate syntax tags.  For that reason alone it should be avoided. Netbeans will highlight matching braces even if they span <?php ?> blocks, but it hasn't a clue how to do so with the alternates.  I think the fact that this question is being asked is further evidence that it should be avoided, to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That style of syntax is more commonly used when embedding in HTML, especially for template/display logic. When embedded this way, it's a little easier to read than the curly braces syntax.

```
<div>
<? if ($condition): ?>
  <ul>
    <? foreach($foo as $bar): ?>
        <li><?= $bar ?></li>
    <? endforeach ?>
  </ul>
<? endif ?>
</div>
```

Versus:

```
<div>
<? if ($condition) { ?>
  <ul>
    <? foreach($foo as $bar) { ?>
      <li><?= $bar ?></li>
    <? } ?>
  </ul>
<? } ?>
```

The verbose end tags make it a little easier to keep track of nested code blocks, although it's still mostly personal preference.

Answer (score 28):

This is PHP's [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Your snippet is equivalent to:

```
if(preg_match('/foo.*bar/','foo is a bar')) {
        echo 'success ';
        echo 'foo comes before bar';
}
```

In general:

```
if(cond):
...
...
endif;
```

is same as

```
if(cond) {
...
...
}
```

Comment: I believe you... but why in Satan's good name would you want to do that?

Comment: @CodeSlave: I suppose it looks nicer if you're embedding html code.

Answer (score 5):

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Works for `if`, `for`, `while`, `foreach`, and `switch`. Can be quite handy for mixing PHP and HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about it in [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) in the PHP manual. Reformatted, the code you posted looks like this:

```
if (preg_match('/foo.*bar/','foo is a bar')):
    echo 'success ';
    echo 'foo comes before bar';
endif;
```

This code is equivalent to:

```
if (preg_match('/foo.*bar/','foo is a bar')) {
    echo 'success ';
    echo 'foo comes before bar';
}
```

This syntax is available for several other control structures as well.

```
if ( condition ):
  // your if code
elseif ( other_condition ):
  // optional elseif code
else:
  // optional else code
endif;

while ( condition ):
  // your while code
endwhile;

for ( condition ):
  // your for code
endfor;

foreach ( condition ):
  // your foreach code
endforeach;

switch ( condition ):
  // your switch code
endswitch;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the equivalent of:

```
if(preg_match('/foo.*bar/','foo is a bar')):
 echo 'success ';
 echo 'foo comes before bar';
endif;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if(preg_match('/foo.*bar/','foo is a bar')){
    echo 'success ';
    echo 'foo comes before bar';
}
```

The wisdom of supporting non-standard conditional syntax is obviously questionable.

Comment: This syntax can be very useful in templates, hence ihmo not questionable. Or at least not obviously;)